# Get source code of external page **using native JS**?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know how to get the source code of an external page using **native, no-library** JavaScript - is it possible?

(Notice: I'm trying to get the JSON contents of a web page like [this one](http://scratch.mit.edu/api/v1/project/1000/?format=json))

I can't use external libraries such as JQuery.

---

Edit - turns out that using the `XMLHttpRequest` works very well, as well as (if I have a server available) I can use...

```
var my_file = <?php echo '"'.file_get_contents("file.json").'"' ?>
```

Also, I can use `JSON.parse()` to get the contents of a file:

```
// Extending from the previous block of code
var my_json = JSON.parse(my_file);
```

Comment: The link you posted is an actual API response of JSON - not the source code of an external page?

Comment: jQuery is native JS. It's just native JS written by other people.

Comment: @tymeJV I know, but I think that getting the source of it will work.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. Are you looking for an introductory tutorial to XMLHttpRequest? Are you looking for information about bypassing the same origin policy? Something else?

Comment: @Quentin Yes, but I can't load any external libraries ideally.

Comment: External as in another domain? You will have security issues there.

Comment: "External libraries" like jQuery are not magical. If you can do it with a library you can do it without one.

Comment: @Juhana Yes, but I'd love to do it without copying any code from the source code. :)

I figure if they can do it I can do it if I know how. XD

Comment: Learn about the XMLHTTPRequest object. It is not magic.

Comment: Right, the answer below just told me that. ;)

Comment: And that answer showed you the bad practice.

Comment: MatthewG is going to update it as he said with a better way.

Comment: Do not just copy the code. Learn about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `XMLHttpRequest` (aka XHR) directly.

```js
var url = "http://scratch.mit.edu/api/v1/project/1000/?format=json";
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false);
xmlHttp.send();
alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
```

The simple example above will do a synchronous request, which will block your UI until the I/O is complete.  You can also make this call asynchronously, processing the result when the I/O is complete.

```js
function success(responseText) {
  alert(responseText);
}

function error(statusText) {
  alert("Error: " + statusText);
}

var url = "http://scratch.mit.edu/api/v1/project/1000/?format=json";
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlHttp.onload = function(e) {
  if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4) {
    if (xmlHttp.status === 200) {
      success(xmlHttp.responseText);
    } else {
      error(xmlHttp.statusText);
    }
  }
};
xmlHttp.onerror = function (e) {
  error(xmlHttp.statusText);
};
  
xmlHttp.send();
```

Comment: OK, true, will add asynchronous example as well.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'll be sure to accept it in a few moments. :)

Comment: Cool, now there's two ways to do it. I'll be sure to look at both.